# SQL Server : Issue with variable and stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SigleEnseigne
     @Sigle VARCHAR OUTPUT,
     @Enseigne VARCHAR OUTPUT,
     @SigleEnseigne1 VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle,'') 
    INTO Sigle 
    FROM John_Jack

    SELECT ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne,'') 
    INTO Enseigne 
    FROM John_Jack

    SELECT 
        CASE 
           WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%' THEN '      / ' + @Enseigne INTO @SigleEnseigne1
           WHEN @Sigle = '' AND @Enseigne = '' THEN '' INTO @SigleEnseigne1
           ELSE @Sigle + ' / ' + @Enseigne INTO @SigleEnseigne1
        END
    FROM John_Jack
END
GO
```

I've got this error code when creating the sp

> Msg 156, Niveau 15, État 1, Procédure SigleEnseigne, Ligne 29
>   Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot clé 'INTO'.

SQL Server doesn't like this line

```
WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%' THEN '      / ' + @Enseigne INTO @SigleEnseigne1
```

Can anyone give me some insight of what I'm doing wrong, please? I'm fairly new to SQL Server, my script may not respect the T-SQL standard. If so, please enlighten me.

Thanks

Comment: @Sigle <> Sigle,also learn to declare the size,VARCHAR is equivalent to VARCAHR(1)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @GiorgiNakeuri, I'm trying to put the relevant column data into the variable `Sigle`,`Enseigne` and `SigleEnseigne1 ` , to be able to retrieve them when I'll use the sp in my reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here:

```
1. Give your types a length
2. Incorrect syntax like `INTO @SigleEnseigne1`
3. You can do this in one go
```

Here is corrected query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SigleEnseigne
    @Sigle VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT ,
    @Enseigne VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT ,
    @SigleEnseigne1 VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT
AS
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1
                @Sigle = ISNULL(Sigle, '') ,
                @Enseigne = ISNULL(Enseigne, '') ,
                @SigleEnseigne1 = CASE WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%'
                                         THEN '      / ' + ISNULL(Enseigne, '')
                                       WHEN ISNULL(Sigle, '') = ''
                                            AND ISNULL(Enseigne, '') = ''
                                         THEN ''
                                       ELSE Sigle + ' / ' Enseigne
                                  END
        FROM    John_Jack
    END
GO
```

But this query makes no sense if `John_Jack` table has more then one row. In such a case you probably need to add some `WHERE` clause to the query to get the row you need.

Comment: This could probably the answer of the question. I have not checked the variable length :(

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri , I'm creating the `sp` to use it on a SSRS report. The previous report was built on crystal report and I'm translating it. From what I've read so far, SSRS should be able to put one record at a time. So I'm trying and if it is not doing what I'm lookingfor , I'll find another way

Comment: `Declare @Sigle VARCHAR(150) , @Enseigne VARCHAR(150) , @SigleEnseigne1 VARCHAR(150) EXEC SigleEnseigne @Sigle OUTPUT, @Enseigne OUTPUT, @SigleEnseigne1 OUTPUT`

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this -

```
SELECT @Sigle = ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle,'') 
FROM John_Jack;

SELECT @Enseigne = ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne,'') 
FROM John_Jack;

SELECT @SigleEnseigne1 = CASE 
                WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%' THEN '      / ' + @Enseigne 
                WHEN @Sigle = '' AND @Enseigne = '' THEN '' 
                ELSE @Sigle + ' / ' + @Enseigne
                END
 FROM John_Jack
```

As you define output variable `@SigleEnseigne1 VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT`.

Comment: You are just dialing with syntax problem. OP has not only the syntax problem.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: Because OP is define output variable as `varchar`.

Comment: Hi @KrishnrajRana , 

First, Thank You.


Please see my comments below my question

Answer (score 1):

It should be more like

```
WHEN something THEN SET @yourVariableField = whatever
```

The INTO statement is more if you're inserting data into a table or table variable